# Getting Data from Previous Page to Transfer to Second Page PHP/MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

so I'm querying some data from my MySQL database to fill out a drop down box dynamically, containing a Date and then a Unique ID for that date (the unique id is a primary key, and increments just in case the same date is in the database).

I'm having trouble accessing the unique ID on the second page which would query the data for the rest of my data based on the date selected. That's kinda confusing so I'll try and break it down.

Table:

===================================================

## |Unique ID|User ID|Weapon|Date|Location|Range|Score|

This is for a marksmanship web page that tracks a user's score.

I have my drop down box accessing the data based on the user ID, and then it populates a dropdown box with

Date - Unique ID.

On the next page, I can get the date fine, but I'm unsure of how to get the Unique ID so I can select the rest of the data based on these two data entries.

Here's my code for this portion:

```
  <!--- Form. Selecting match and all the data under it. !--->
<form action = "retrieved.php"  method = "post" style="margin-bottom:0px">

<select name="date"><option value="">-- Select A Date --</option>
<?php
    // While there is a row of data, print out the date to the drop down box.
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
          echo("</option><option value=". $row['date'] . ">". $row['date'] . " 
| Unique ID: " . $row['uniqueID'] . "
                </option>");
      }
 ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Retrieve Data" />
</form>

E.G. 
DropdownBox Options:
2014-08-16 | Unique ID: 5
2014-09-17 | Unique ID: 8
2014-09-17 | Unique ID: 10
2014-09-17 | Unique ID: 25
```

I thought about having Two Dropdown boxes where the user selects a date and then the second dropdown has the Unique ID which would update dynamically using AJAX or jquery or something, but I'm unfamiliar with those, and would still need to know how to access the data on the next page....

My second page needs something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM matches WHERE id = '".$id."' AND date = '".$date."' AND uniqueID = '".$uniqueID'"; but I can't get the uniqueID variable to work. I tried using $_SESSION and $_POST but nothing is saving to the next page.
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: In the end, I want to be able to access all the data (weapon, range, score, etc) corresponding to the date and Unique ID selected.

Comment: on the second page you will get the values in a $_POST array. eg: $_POST['date'] for the date field on the first page.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha yes but OP wants the `uniqueID` too!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: what is OP?

Comment: You can do one of two things, to keep it HTML/PHP based and not bother with javascript, you can make the `value` of the select hold both values separated by a unique `delimiter` which could for example be `@` and then split that out in PHP.  Alternatively you can add a `data` attribute via jQuery and submit the form via AJAX. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @SaurabhSinha it means 'Original Poster'

Comment: Show the query that fill the dropdown will help us to understand what you need.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha I can use $_POST['date'] and that gets the selected date fine, but using $_POST['uniqueID'] gets me nothing....

Rob, how would I go about storing both values separated by a delim?

Comment: If your "uniqueID" is actually unique, just use that as the value attribute in the dropdown. There is no point to query for a match in date AND uniqueID, if the uniqueID is actually unique.

Comment: I could do that, but to the user of the page, he is not gonna be able to keep track of the match ID, and won't be able to easily identify which match it is based upon just the ID...whereas knowing the date, it's far much easier to remember which match is which based on a date.

Also, since it's one database, the uniqueID will jump around because it's a primary key, and is not based upon per user, but the database. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the unique id in the value field of your option:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo(
 "</option><option value='". $row['date'] . ",".$row['uniqueId']."'>".                           </option>"
);
}
```

Then when retrieving the value on the next page use:

```
$valueArray = explode(',', $value);
```

This will yield an array like so:

```
['date', 'uniqueID']
```

Your query will look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM matches WHERE uniqueId = ".$valueArray[0] ." AND date     =".$valueArray[1]."
```

**Note**

Your query here is highly susceptible to [SqlInjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

You should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or some other [orm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

To manage your queries and mitigate the risks of malicious sql being injected.

Comment: whats the difference between using the comma and > when I'm creating the option values? When I use your way, the right amount of drop down values are created, but they're all blank.

Comment: @Shinku443 I don't think there should be much difference in using the > or the comma as a delimeter. Though, it is generally a bad practice to delimit with operators like >. Because, it can cause confusion especially when you are concantenating html strings.

Comment: hmm...well I tried using your way but it didn't work at all, like the drop down box doesn't get filled with anything. it's just white. the only difference is the comma instead of the '>'

Comment: @Shinku443 Sorry for the confusion. You notice in my example I am delimiting, the value with a comma. You aren't actually delimiting the value at all in  your example. So your result will be <option value='somedate'> and mine will be <option value='somedate,someuniqueid'> If it is not rendering then you should inspect the element in your browser, more likely than not you have an error in your concantenation.

Comment: AHHH i got it! It's because the way you had it only gave the value, but To have it shown it needs to be:
<option value="2014"> 2014 </option>
I got it working based on your code, thank you so much! :)